# How to implement Individual Column Searching using checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

This is my sample of datatables with checkboxes: http://live.datatables.net/kayedefu/1/edit

How do I implement Individual Column Searching using checkboxes?

I am currently stuck and it seems I've done some of my solutions such as modifying the JS but it's not working.

For example: If a user checks the "Name" checkbox, the user can only search values in in the column "Name". While the "Name" is currently checked, if a user enters a value that is not included in the column "Name", it will show no data.

All suggestions and solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()

Comment: Combine `column().search()` with a [column selector](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector). You can then create an array of column indexes `var checkedCols = [ 2, 4, 5]` to search in, based on the checkboxes. And then use `columns( checkedCols )`.